# error in flutter while using onTap

Tags: android, widget, flutter

i get the following error while using **onTap** in flutter. The error i get is:

```
Crash when compiling file:///C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/01502039_Velkov_A3/test_app/lib/pages/landing_page.dart,
at character offset 135:
lib/pages/landing_page.dart:10:16: Internal problem: Unhandled () → void => dart.core::print("We tapped") in defaultTreeNode.
        onTap: ()=> print("We tapped"),
```

And my code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Material(
      color: Colors.greenAccent,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: ()=> print("We tapped"),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text("Lets do a quizz", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            new Text("Tap to start!", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm following a tutorial and the guy does it without any problems, but in my case this happens. I'm new to flutter so i have no idea how to fix stuff like that. Is there a problem with the arrow function?

Comment: What Flutter version? `flutter --version`

Comment: Flutter version 0.2.8

Comment: I'd try a newer Flutter version `flutter channel dev` (or `flutter channel master`)

Comment: it worked!! Thanks a lot for your reply.